# Drop columns in Sybase ASE table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

How can I drop a column in a Sybase ASE 15 table setup.

I have tried a few, to no avail:

```
alter table my_table
drop column1, column2
```

As well as looking at the [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/BABCGFHG.htm) which provides no solution to my issues.

> The 'select into' database option is not enabled for database
>   'my_db'. ALTER TABLE with data copy cannot be done. Set the 'select
>   into' database option and re-run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your `select into` option on database is off, there are two option either you ON the `select into` option using

```
sp_dboption my_db, "select into", true
```

OR

The `no datacopy` parameter to the alter table drop column allows you to drop columns from a table without performing a data copy, and reduces the amount of time required for alter table drop column to run.

[SYBASE Documentation - Dropping Columns from a Table Without Performing a Data Copy](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1572/html/new_features/new_features65.htm)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
DROP column1, column2
WITH no datacopy
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'"

Comment: `sp_dboption my_db, "select into", true` did not work on mine but replacing double quotes to single quotes did work

Answer (score 3):

Just want to share with you I've just had similar issue, and in my case I had to add "drop" before each column name. The code looks like this:

```
alter table dba.ABC
drop column1,
drop column2,
drop column3

commit;
```

I work on some old version of sybase that is not that flexible.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the keyword 'COLUMN' in your query. Use following syntax:-

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
DROP COLUMN column1, column2
```

Comment: That's not Sybase syntax, though I did try that. I found my solution.

Comment: I was also shocked to see, that COLUMN keyword is not mentioned in the DOCUMENTION. But i think it is the default ANSI syntax used everywhere. But most importantly you forgot to accept my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, the fact that "select into" has to be turned on means that the Sybase server is internally copying the data from the old table to a new copy of the table, without using the transaction logs (or using transaction logs only to log the allocation of pages, not the data change within the page).  Ie. sort of like bulkcopy.  I wonder if this causes any problems for replication?

Also, just for completeness, the "no datacopy" feature is new, as of version 15.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My new test database had the 'select into' option turned off, meaning the removal/alterations of tables were being rejected.

i.e.

`sp_dboption my_db, "select into", true`

It all looks so obvious now that I know what the options are.